# Add an BankAccount through Stripe API in Java

Tags: java, stripe-payments

I am looking to add a bankAccount to a Connect Account in Stripe through the API. I'm using the test numbers given and I followed the instructions. The account has already set an AccountLink and it is of Custom type (Express has also been tried)

```
Stripe.apiKey = stripePrivate;

    Account account = Account.retrieve(accountId);
    Map<String, Object> bankParams = new HashMap<>();
    bankParams.put("object", "bank_account");
    bankParams.put("country", "US");
    bankParams.put("currency", "usd");
    bankParams.put("routing_number", "110000000");
    bankParams.put("account_number", "000123456789");

    BankAccount bankAccount = (BankAccount) account.getExternalAccounts().create(bankParams);
```

It appears that it is not recognizing the parameters as I get the following error:

```
"Received unknown parameters: account_number, object, routing_number, currency,country; code: parameter_unknown; request-id: req_ANeBN5XHeh2ki0"
```

The Stripe version is 22.4

Comment: I have also tried using the token as shown in the Docs: https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create?lang=java

Comment: And creating a new BankAccount object and setting manually the parameters, but accountNumber is not available as it shouldn't be for security

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So this is a bit trickier and I think it should have been better documented for what it's worth. You first need to start by creating a bank account token using the token API as shown [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/tokens/create_bank_account?lang=java). This will generate a token `btok_xxx` that you will need then to use to create an external bank account for your Custom Account as shown [here](https://stripe.com/docs/api/external_account_bank_accounts/create?lang=java)

Answer (score 0):

Correct code is:

```
bankParams.put("external_account[object]","bank_account");
bankParams.put("external_account[country]","US");
bankParams.put("external_account[currency]","USD");
bankParams.put("external_account[routing_number]", "110000000");
bankParams.put("external_account[account_number]", "000123456789");
```

As Stripe doc says:

> "external_account is either a token, like the ones returned by Stripe.js, or a dictionary containing a user’s bank account details"

In http syntax, "Dictionary" params are passed through with square brackets...